# How to print elements of one class using variable of another class?

Tags: arrays, swift, class, methods, swift3

I have created two classes a Person class and a food class. Now i am making list of all the food items consumed in a year by a particular person. I want to print all of them separated by commas

Here's my code

```
class Food {
        let name: String
        var EatenBy: Person?
        init(name: String){
            self.name = name
        }
    }
```

And my Person class is as follows

```
class Person {
        var name: String
        var foods: [Food] = []

        lazy var foodNames: () -> String = {
            return "" 
        }

        init(name: String){
            self.name = name
        }

        func adopt(food: Food){
            foods.append(food)
            food.EatenBy = self
        }
    }
```

Now i want to create different food items using the Food class and then assign it to a person who have consumed them and store it in an array foods.

```
var person = Person(name: "Test")

var pasta = Food(name: "pasta")
```

Can anyone help me out how can i use the objects created using Food class and assign it to a object created in the Person class and append them in the foods array ?

My final aim is to print all the elements in the foods array separating them using commas or spaces or such, which i guess can be easily done by looping each of the element through a for loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `Person` instance, you can access its properties (including the `foods` array by the dot syntax: `person.foods`.

For printing the food names, you should declare `foodNames` as a computed property. As its return value, just use `map` to get the names of each `Food` instance, then use `[String].joined(separator: ",")` to join the contents of the array of Strings into a single String.

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    var foods: [Food] = []

    var foodNames:String {
        return foods.map{$0.name}.joined(separator: ",")
    }

    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    }

    func adopt(food: Food){
        foods.append(food)
        food.EatenBy = self
    }
}

class Food {
    let name: String
    var EatenBy: Person?
    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    }
}

let john = Person(name: "John")
let pasta = Food(name: "pasta")
john.foods = [pasta, Food(name: "tuna")] //assign an array to the variable directly
john.foods.append(Food(name: "tomato")) //or append the existing array

john.adopt(food: Food(name: "bread")) //you can also use your _adopt_ function to add an element to the _foods_ array of a _Person_ instance

john.foodNames // "pasta, tuna, tomato,bread"
```

It looks like you are missing some basic concepts of how Swift works (like using the dot syntax to access class properties), so I would recommend reading [The Swift Programming Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) as a start, it is a really useful starting point for a beginner Swift developer.

Comment: Thank you works just as i required. Thanks for the link too, i will go through it.

Comment: Another Swift lesson is to not make everything a class. `Person` makes sense because each instance is unique; it has identity. But having a `Food` class does not. Two different instances of Bean would have two different `eatenBy` references. Ownership is already defined by being included in the Person object. i.e. Iterate through all Persons to find those with Beans in its foods array. `Food` could be a struct or enum.

Comment: @PriceRingo it depends on the exact usage of such classes. It can make sense to make `Food` a class, for example if these were database classes, it would make sense, to have a bidirectional relationship between the two classes.

Comment: Absolutely right but now we are reading more into the requirements than what was stated.